# extjs columnmodel, columns resizing

Tags: extjs, extjs3

How to listen for the re-sizing of columns in the following column model :

```
new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
    columns : [{
          }]
```

I have tried resize, columnresize, oncolumnresize. None of them are listening for the width change in a column. I want to listen to the change in width of a column and perform actions accordingly.

```
$(element).width().bind('change',...);
$(element).bind('resize', function() {
```

I had tried the above options as well and they do not work.

Can I listen to in the column listeners or handle it in jquery. Which can be done and what works properly?

Note: I think my extjs version is 3

Comment: If you wanna know which version of extjs you have, open your app in Chrome, press F12 on your keyboard to open the developer tools, CTRL + O to list le js file, now search for ext-all.js or ext-all-debug.js. In the header you will see: This file is part of Ext JS 3.4. After that, you will be able to add extj3 on you StackOverflow tag. Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelLane, I saw the version, its 3

Answer (score 1):

I used the `listeners` property for `column` to listen to `resize` event to achieve it:

```
  columns : [{
             text: 'Name',
             dataIndex: 'Name',
             flex: 1,
            listeners:{
               resize:function (ct, width, eOpts) {
                      //your code goes here
                }
              }
             }]
```

Comment: mine is extjs3, resize is not an event for a column.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ExtJS 3, you should look into the docs for ExtJS 3.4.0, and not into any newer docs.

And if you do that, you see [that there are only very few events available on columns, and `resize` isn't one of them](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column-event-click).

You could now stop searching, but if I were you, I wouldn't.

Because if you look at the ColumnModel, you find the event [`widthchange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.ColumnModel-event-widthchange), which does fire when the width of a column is changed programmatically, and that very docs entry has a reference to event you search, which is [`columnresize`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-columnresize) on the GridPanel(!).

Comment: but that wont be helpful because I do not use grid panel. I also have seen the widthchange event, but it wont fire when the user resizes from the UI. So is there any other way, or any type of jquery, can it work?